# Remove the border of the input and change color of the placeholder in buefy

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I want remove the bordes, because I want to leave only the bottom. And the other help me, change color of the placeholder.

With the css I applied, the edge of the input looks strange.

[image]

```
        <b-field label="Username:"
            :type="{ 'is-danger': this.hasError }"
            :message="{ 'Username is not available': this.hasError }">
            <b-input v-model="username" value='' maxlength="30" placeholder="Username"></b-input>
        </b-field>

        .input{
           color: #dce3ff;
           background-color: #394573;
           border:0px;
           border-bottom:2px solid #eee;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Customize SCSS Bulma variables for this.
For example, if you want to change Input Placeholder color, you can change the value for `$input-placeholder-color`.

About the border removal, Bulma Style also use `box-shadow`. This is what you see at the edge of your input. You can customize Bulma `$input-shadow` variable to `$input-shadow: none;`